Counting subsets of 7 elements from a N-elements set
How can I count the number of 7-elements subsets from a N-elements set containing the N first not null natural integers?
With the following constraint for the output subsets:
$$ E_{j} = \{
n_{1}, n_{2},..., n_{7} \colon  n_{i} \leq n_{i+1} \}$$
As you notice, repetition is allowed then must be included.
Let's define a specific example with N=10. Therefore the main set to count those 7-elements subsets from is: $$ \begin{Bmatrix}
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \end{Bmatrix} $$

Does this answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition ?

Basically yes, thank you.
I don't know why, when I first read about this I was not convinced it duplicated subsets depending of the order. ex: {2, 1, 2} and {1, 2, 2}. But it doesn't so that's perfect.
In my case because I want the subsets ordered in lists for a program, I just have to generate the 7-multicombinations from my set of N elements, then order elements from each one by ascending order (if they're not already).

Thanks to the replies, I simply realized the correct binomial coefficient for counting this is the following: $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$
If I want to generate all k-multicombinations I just have to take care that each subset list is ordered by ascending order.
